# Scikit learn Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, csv, scikit-learn

Во многих примерах `Scikit learn` (родная справка) указаны массивы:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import RepeatedKFold
X = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [1, 2], [3, 4]])
```

А как быть, если у меня `csv` файл?

Как можно преобразовать `csv`, чтоб использовать массивы как указаны в примере?

Пример CSV файла:

```
1,14.23,1.71,2.43,15.6,127,2.8,3.06,.28,2.29,5.64,1.04,3.92,‌​1065
1,13.2,1.78,2.14,11.2,100,2.65,2.76,.26,1.28,4.38,1.05,3.4,1‌​050
1,13.16,2.36,2.67,18.6,101,2.8,3.24,.3,2.81,5.68,1.03,3.17,1‌​185
1,14.37,1.95,2.5,16.8,113,3.85,3.49,.24,2.18,7.8,.86,3.45,14‌​80
1,13.24,2.59,2.87,21,118,2.8,2.69,.39,1.82,4.32,1.04,2.93,73‌​5
1,14.2,1.76,2.45,15.2,112,3.27,3.39,.34,1.97,6.75,1.05,2.85,‌​1450
1,14.39,1.87,2.45,14.6,96,2.5,2.52,.3,1.98,5.25,1.02,3.58,12‌​90
1,14.06,2.15,2.61,17.6,121,2.6,2.51,.31,1.25,5.05,1.06,3.58,‌​1295
```

Comment: вы хотите спросить как прочитать данные из csv файла в numpy массив? Связанный вопрос [How to read csv into record array in numpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3518778/4279)

Comment: Прочитать могу. Например есть csv файл (300 строчек и 18 столбцов). Как он будет выглядеть  в форме массива, т.е array [ ]?

Comment: @Андрей, приведите небольшой (например - 10 тсрок и 5 столбцов) пример CSV файла (в виде текста - так, чтобы его можно было скопировать)

Comment: 1,14.23,1.71,2.43,15.6,127,2.8,3.06,.28,2.29,5.64,1.04,3.92,1065
1,13.2,1.78,2.14,11.2,100,2.65,2.76,.26,1.28,4.38,1.05,3.4,1050
1,13.16,2.36,2.67,18.6,101,2.8,3.24,.3,2.81,5.68,1.03,3.17,1185
1,14.37,1.95,2.5,16.8,113,3.85,3.49,.24,2.18,7.8,.86,3.45,1480
1,13.24,2.59,2.87,21,118,2.8,2.69,.39,1.82,4.32,1.04,2.93,735                   
1,14.2,1.76,2.45,15.2,112,3.27,3.39,.34,1.97,6.75,1.05,2.85,1450
1,14.39,1.87,2.45,14.6,96,2.5,2.52,.3,1.98,5.25,1.02,3.58,1290
1,14.06,2.15,2.61,17.6,121,2.6,2.51,.31,1.25,5.05,1.06,3.58,1295

В pandas открывает эти значение

Comment: читаете из  CSV файла применяя функцию преобразования float().
и все.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import RepeatedKFold

df = pd.read_csv(filename, header=None)
print(df)

rkf = RepeatedKFold(n_splits=2, n_repeats=2)

y = df[0].values                # первый столбец DataFrame
X = df.drop(0, axis=1).values   # все столбцы DF кроме первого
print('=' * 80)

for train_index, test_index in rkf.split(X):
    print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)
    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
```

Вывод:

```
   0      1     2     3     4    5     6     7     8     9     10    11    12    13
0   1  14.23  1.71  2.43  15.6  127  2.80  3.06  0.28  2.29  5.64  1.04  3.92  1065
1   1  13.20  1.78  2.14  11.2  100  2.65  2.76  0.26  1.28  4.38  1.05  3.40  1050
2   1  13.16  2.36  2.67  18.6  101  2.80  3.24  0.30  2.81  5.68  1.03  3.17  1185
3   1  14.37  1.95  2.50  16.8  113  3.85  3.49  0.24  2.18  7.80  0.86  3.45  1480
4   1  13.24  2.59  2.87  21.0  118  2.80  2.69  0.39  1.82  4.32  1.04  2.93   735
5   1  14.20  1.76  2.45  15.2  112  3.27  3.39  0.34  1.97  6.75  1.05  2.85  1450
6   1  14.39  1.87  2.45  14.6   96  2.50  2.52  0.30  1.98  5.25  1.02  3.58  1290
7   1  14.06  2.15  2.61  17.6  121  2.60  2.51  0.31  1.25  5.05  1.06  3.58  1295
================================================================================

TRAIN: [0 1 4 6] TEST: [2 3 5 7]
TRAIN: [2 3 5 7] TEST: [0 1 4 6]
TRAIN: [1 2 3 4] TEST: [0 5 6 7]
TRAIN: [0 5 6 7] TEST: [1 2 3 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
infile = open('data.csv', 'r')
import csv
table = []
for row in csv.reader(infile):
    table.append([float(x) for x in row])
infile.close()
print(table)
```

это если без пандас ))
там в массив перекинете сами
хотя так медленнее